# Android app: How to add coordinates dynamically to a map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make an app that will follow a device that emits coordinates every few seconds.
I have a map that displays my current location as a blue circle, but I want to additionally add a blue circle, like the one for my location, with the coordinates from the device I am trying to track. If anyone has any help it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have the coordinates?

Comment: Call `addMarker` on the `GoogleMap` using the desired coordinates, and use a custom `drawable` that you've imported into the project (in this case, the blue circle).

Comment: I do have the coordinates @user3249477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a simple marker and add it to your map:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
```

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) answer simple questions like this one.